# Debug Unity DLLs in Windows standalone build

Tags: unity, debugging, deployment

I'm trying to publish a game on the Windows Store using a standalone Windows build in Unity 5.6.2 and Desktop Bridge. Despite unchecking "development build", three Unity DLLs remain in debug mode, which blocks deployment:

- The binary UnityEngine.Networking.dll is built in debug mode.
- The binary UnityEngine.UI.dll is built in debug mode.
- The binary UnityEngine.dll is built in debug mode.

How can I force Unity to give me release DLLs if unchecking "development build" isn't enough?